# "Unhandled auth type: app, user" from dropbox api

Tags: python, dropbox-api

Until the other day I was able to read files using the dropbox API, but now I get an authentication error.

```
!pip install dropbox
import dropbox
import time
    
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(<Access Token>)
dir = <folder_path>

lists = []
def __get_files_recursive(res):
    for entry in res.entries:
        ##print(list(entry.path_display.split(",")))
        lists.append(entry.path_display.split(","))
        ##print(lists)
        print(entry.path_display)

    if (res.has_more):
        res2 = dbx.files_list_folder_continue(res.cursor)
        __get_files_recursive(res2)

res = dbx.files_list_folder(dir, recursive=True)
__get_files_recursive(res)
```

Error Code was as follows

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BadInputException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-f64dcbce5290> in <module>()
     12         __get_files_recursive(res2)
     13 
---> 14 res = dbx.files_list_folder(dir, recursive=True)
     15 __get_files_recursive(res)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dropbox/dropbox_client.py in request_json_string(self, host, func_name, route_style, request_json_arg, auth_type, request_binary, timeout)
    562             pass
    563         else:
--> 564             raise BadInputException('Unhandled auth type: {}'.format(auth_type))
    565 
    566         # The contents of the body of the HTTP request

BadInputException: Unhandled auth type: app, user
```

If you know how to solve this problem, please let me know.

Comment: This appears to be an issue in the latest version of the Dropbox Python SDK (v11.13.0). We'll look into it. Please downgrade to v11.12.0 for now.

Comment: This is fixed in v11.13.1 now.

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation.
I was able to do it without any problems.